# Java ArrayList: create a copy of array and use seperate from old, but don't create new objects

Tags: java, object, reference

For example, I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Animal> zoo = new ArrayList<Animal>();
// some code to add animals to zoo
```

I want to create a copy of this `old zoo` to `new zoo`, and I can use remove/add... to process this new zoo.(and of course, it will not affect to old zoo). So, I have a way that: create new zoo that  clone each animals in old zoo (it means create animal objects).
So, it too SLOW.

I have an another way: create a reference of each animals of old zoo and copy to new zoo. So, new zoo just hold reference to animals of zoo. So, each time I remove/add,... It just delete reference to animal objects. No affect old zoo, and NO CREATE a new object.

But, I don't know how to do it in Java. Please teach me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple in Java:

```
ArrayList<Animal> copy = new ArrayList<Animal>(zoo);
```

The constructor [`ArrayList<T>(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) performs a *shallow copy* of the list that you supply as parameter, which is precisely the semantics that you are looking for.

Comment: Oh. Thanks :) I understand shallow copy in Java, but I don't know use this is also shallow copy,too. (It's so strange with me when use on Collections).

Answer (score 5):

Simply try :

```
ArrayList<Animal> newZoo = new ArrayList<Animal>(oldZoo);
```